# Jquery Validation Remote: displaying 1 as error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate username field in my form using jquery validation plugin. I have the following custom rules.

```
username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            remote: {
                url: '<?php echo base_url();?>mycontoller/myfunction',
                type: 'post'
            }
```

Now the problem is if  my controller looks like following the plugin displays "1" as error message.

```
     if(1>2){
                echo False;
            } else{ echo True;}
```

But if I replace the code of the controller with following code, then it display an error message saying-  the username already exists.

```
     if(1<2){
                echo False;
            } else{ echo True;}
```

Now could you please tell me how to get rid of that "1" or what is the proper way to send back the values(false or true) from controller to view.

Just for your information. I am displaying all my jquery validation error messages inside a span.
like this.

```
         <span class="errormsg"></span>.
```

Comment: "the username already exists" doesn't sound like a jquery.validation error, are you sure this error isn't coming from your server side validation?

Gonna need more information/code.

Comment: @Greg B, I set the message. like this `remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where I'm sure you will find an answer: http://www.opencoder.co.uk/2010/07/jquery-remote-form-validation/

Comment: I had to add to replace `url: '<?php echo base_url();?>mycontoller/myfunction',` with `url: '<?php echo base_url();?>mycontoller/myfunction', async: false`  to make it work. :) thanks :)

Comment: But could you please tell me what is `async: false`?

Comment: The reason your remote validation function did not work properly is because the remote validation checking was done asynchronously, as is the ajax request. Your form submit event binding function checks first if the form is valid before doing the ajax submit. The trouble is that the remote validation is done asynchronously. So the valid check is just returning true instead of false. In order to solve this the remote validation needs to be done synchronously instead (which is setting  async: false).